# Saving values from a (Float) ArrayList into a Bundle

Tags: arrays, arraylist, floating-point, integer, bundle

I'm writing a game using Surfaceview and have a question relating to saving Data into a Bundle.

Initially, I had an arraylist which stored the Y co-ordinates (in the form of Integers) of sprites that will move only up and down. Declared as:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> ycoordinates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I saved them to a Bundle using the following:

```
myBundle.putIntegerArrayList("myycoordinates", ycoordinates);
```

And restored them using this:

```
ycoordinates.addAll(savedState.getIntegerArrayList("ycoordinates"));
```

This all worked perfectly.  However, I've had to change the whole coordinates system so it's based on Delta time to allow my sprites to move at a uniform speed across different screens.  This is, again, working perfectly.

However, as a result of this change, I now have to store these values as floats rather than integers.

So, I am declaring as:

```
static ArrayList<Float> ycoordinates = new ArrayList<Float>();
```

So that's the background, now my question is, how do I store and restore values from a Float Arraylist?  There doesn't seem to be a "putFloatArrayList" or "getFloatArrayList".

(I've used an Arraylist rather than an Array as the number of sprites needs to be dynamic).

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: The number of sprites presumably does not change while it is in the bundle, so you could store it as an array, and convert back to a list when you restore.

Comment: Great Idea Patricia, thanks, any idea how I convert an Arraylist to an Array? Is it a simple thing to do? Thanks again.

Comment: I suggest reading about the List toArray() method.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, you need a float[], not the Float[] toArray would give you. I've written a couple of utility methods to do the conversions, and posted them in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a couple of simple methods to convert between List and float[]. You can use the Bundle `putFloatArray()` and `getFloatArray` on the float[].

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Float> in = new ArrayList<Float>();
    in.add(3.0f);
    in.add(1f);
    in.add((float)Math.PI);
    List<Float>out = toList(toArray(in));
    System.out.println(out);
  }

  public static float[] toArray(List<Float> in){
    float[] result = new float[in.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
      result[i] = in.get(i);
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static List<Float> toList(float[] in){
    List<Float> result = new ArrayList<Float>(in.length);
    for(float f : in){
      result.add(f);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```